# Verify that dynamically created CSS indeed loaded

Tags: javascript, html, loading

I cannot find a way to identify whether the CSS, which was created dynamically via creating a `<link>` tag and then specifying the `href` attribute had indeed loaded.

Consider the following example:

```
var css = document.createElement("link");
css.href = "not-a-directory/not-a-css";
document.body.appendChild(css);
```

Some browsers (Firefox), will dispatch `"onload"` event even if the path doesn't designate an existing file, however, this would only happen if sandbox policies would have not been violated, if file existed. Opera, Google Chrome and Safari - all report the problem in some way, but I can't find a way to handle that in JavaScript.

I'm not interested in supporting MS Internet Explorer (the project will be deployed to embedded WebKit / Opera browsers), but if there is a crossplatform way - that's, of course, welcomed.

PS. `"onerror"` doesn't seem to trigger in any browser.

**CLARIFICATION**

Sorry, I had to provide more info. Now I'll try to fix that:

1. I prefer not to use other libraries (like jQuery), but if they solved it somehow, that's a valid solution, if I can take a look at how they did it.
2. The code will be deployed to either Opera or WebKit browsers on SmartTV (read it as severe size limitations + files may be required to load from file-system rather than from the net). This is why I can't use `XMLHttpRequest`.
3. If you can think of a way to test whether the text file exists given the path (think `iframe`, `link` - perhaps other elements?) That is a good option too.

Comment: check on firebug to see if the dynamically generated css is loaded properly or not

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after much struggle, here's what I did (but alternative solutions are welcome!):

Created a class with the name which is unlikely to happen in other CSS files, say:

```
.x29048723049820394 { color: #514159 }
```

and then created a `div` tag in the HTML page, where I wanted to test whether the CSS has indeed loaded. After creating a `link` tag (don't forget - you also need to specify the `rel` attribute, otherwise the style won't load), I set timer to wait for the `div` I just created to change color. After the color changed I'd assume that the CSS had loaded. Or if the time ran out, I'd give up, assuming that the CSS didn't load.

On the way I also discovered, that in case the CSS file is loaded from the file system, even the same directory as the original HTML, which requests it, you will run into security-related errors when either trying to access the `innerHTML` of the `link` or when trying to iterate through the style sheets of the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a specific class name that should be loaded then you could use javascript to loop through all the style sheets and class names to see if it was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that there's no elegant and reliable way of detecting it, everything is more or less hacks.

Here's my hack off the top of my head:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/style.css",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (cssString) {
            // css file exists, and was loaded correctly.
            $("head").append($("<style/>").text(cssString));
        },
        error: function (e) {
            // css file did not exist, we can check status code with e.status (404 etc)
        }
    });
```

We basically load the css file as text using ajax and then attach the loaded data to the dom. This way we can reliably detect failures, but other than that it's a total hack. You most likely get a flash of unstyled content. I'm not sure I would use it, but I thought it might be fun to throw it out there along with all other hacks :-)